# How to make jQuery load AFTER plugin's script?

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I've read about and configured my own scripts using

```
wp_enqueue_script
```

and setting my script as jQuery-dependant, but how can I reorder jQuery when the script is from a plugin?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function ytc_init_MPAU() {jQuery('.ytc-lightbox').magnificPopupAU({disableOn:320,type:'iframe',mainClass:'ytc-mfp-lightbox',removalDelay:160,preloader:false,fixedContentPos:false});}jQuery(window).on('load',function(){ytc_init_MPAU();});jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ytc_init_MPAU();});
            </script>
            <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css' href='http://elinfluencer.dosdev.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all'/>
            <link rel='stylesheet' id='thickbox-css' href='http://elinfluencer.dosdev.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=4.8' type='text/css' media='all'/>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
```

Comment: Looks like you're not using the jQuery that comes with WP core. That would be your issue. Instead of dequeuing core jQuery and enqueueing a version from Google, just make your plugin script dependent on core's version of jQuery.

Comment: [edit] your question and share your code instead of screenshot please

Comment: @WebElaine: I'll take a look at that. This is legacy installation, not one that I created. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score -1):

Just as @WebElaine observed, jQuery was being used incorrectly and twice. I removed the external call and edited my script accordingly to use the core's version.

Thanks.